# Isotope events not firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm using Isotope for its awesome layout capabilites, I have a call that retrieves new items via Ajax, this removes the old items and prepends the new ones. The animation looks really slick, however I can not get a call back to work on the animation being complete.

I am attempting to use this from their documentation on their site:

```
$grid.on( 'arrangeComplete', onArrange );
```

I have implemented it this way:

```
$grid = $('#grid').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item'
});

$grid.on('arrangeComplete', function(){
    console.log('arrangeComplete')
});
```

However this just isn't working for me. The event is never fired.

I have two functions for removing and prepending the new items:

```
//Remove
$grid.isotope('remove', removeItems); //removeItems being a var this works fine

//Add
$grid
    .prepend(assets)
    .isotope('appended', assets)
    .isotope('reloadItems')
    .isotope({sortby: 'original-order'});
//again this all works fine
```

I'm not sure if I'm using the wrong event for the completion of animation but the trouble I have is that none of them seem to be firing.

At the moment I have a hack in place:

```
$grid.bind("transitionend", function(){
```

The hack works, but its firing its event at the end of each element transition which means depending on how many items on the page it will fire for all of their transitions to remove, and then all of the transitions for the next items being prepended. This is obviously a problem for me.

Any help or pointers on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you wrap your code in a `function(){}` or DOM ready ?

Comment: Yes, they are all broken into separate functions for clearing, adding and of course the initializing of the instance. Its in the initialization that I have actually included the `.on('arrangeComplete'...`

Comment: I mean this: `$(document).ready({ $grid.isotope({...})})`

Comment: Of course, they are all fired from within `$(function(){...})`

Comment: Try re-initializing isotope on success at ajax call.

Comment: I have just tried this and it is still not firing the event

Comment: Would you please bring more html and ajax codes

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've had trouble with the `reloadItems` method not firing, causing dynamically added items to stack in the top right corner. For some reason, calling it the following way seems to work:

```
$grid.isotope('reloadItems').isotope();
```

I have no idea why the second .isotope() is necessary - maybe someone else could explain.

Comment: There is a description from the plugin author here (although it is a few years old): https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope/issues/238